# Predicting mouse written digits

Tags: python, opencv, tensorflow, machine-learning, image-processing

I wanted to predict digits written by mouse.
I created a model using TensorFlow and trained the whole dataset.

When I write a digit and try to predict, it gives me answers with less accuracy.

Please suggest some ways to overcome this.

The source code is:

```
import cv2
import numpy as np 
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from PIL import Image
import tensorflow as tf

def plot_digit(data):
    image = data.reshape(28, 28)
    plt.imshow(image, interpolation='nearest')
    plt.axis('off')

mnist = tf.keras.datasets.mnist

(x_train, y_train), (x_test, y_test) = mnist.load_data()
x_train, x_test = x_train / 255.0, x_test / 255.0

model = tf.keras.models.Sequential([
  tf.keras.layers.Flatten(input_shape=(28, 28)),
  tf.keras.layers.Dense(128, activation='relu'),
  tf.keras.layers.Dropout(0.2),
  tf.keras.layers.Dense(128, activation='relu'),
  tf.keras.layers.Dense(10)
])

predictions = model(x_train[:1]).numpy()
tf.nn.softmax(predictions).numpy()

loss_fn = tf.keras.losses.SparseCategoricalCrossentropy(from_logits=True)
loss_fn(y_train[:1], predictions).numpy()

model.compile(optimizer='adam',
              loss=loss_fn,
              metrics=['accuracy'])

model.fit(x_train, y_train, epochs=10)

model.evaluate(x_test,  y_test, verbose=2)

drawing = False # true if mouse is pressed
pt1_x , pt1_y = None , None

# mouse callback function
def line_drawing(event,x,y,flags,param):
    global pt1_x,pt1_y,drawing

    if event==cv2.EVENT_LBUTTONDOWN:
        drawing=True
        pt1_x,pt1_y=x,y

    elif event==cv2.EVENT_MOUSEMOVE:
        if drawing==True:
            cv2.line(img,(pt1_x,pt1_y),(x,y),color=(255,255,255),thickness=3)
            pt1_x,pt1_y=x,y
    elif event==cv2.EVENT_LBUTTONUP:
        drawing=False
        cv2.line(img,(pt1_x,pt1_y),(x,y),color=(255,255,255),thickness=3)        


img = np.zeros((200,200), np.uint8)
cv2.namedWindow('test draw')
cv2.setMouseCallback('test draw',line_drawing)

while(1):
    cv2.imshow('test draw',img)
    if cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF == 27:
        break
cv2.destroyAllWindows()

img = Image.fromarray(img)
foo = img.resize((28,28),Image.ANTIALIAS)
foo = np.array(foo)/255.0
plot_digit(foo)

np.argmax(model.predict(foo.reshape(1,28,28)))
```

When I write 7, it predicts 6.
But when I plot the figure I've drawn, it shows 7.

Comment: if you plot 8 does it predict 7? If yes then maybe you need to adjust the index of the predicted digit

Comment: It isn't about the index. When I write 3, it prints 8.

Comment: then train better with more samples for 3 and 8 for example so it can distinguish between the two

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This could be a lot of things. Some ideas:

1) Maybe it's the resizing? With `thickness=3` on a `200,200`, that becomes more like `thickness=1` after you resize to `(28,28)`, which no longer represents the MNIST dataset. Try visualising some MNIST data and mouse written data, and see if they really are similar (at the `(28,28)`) level.

2) Maybe the model overfits to handwritten digits? Consider using convolutional layers in your model, I think it would mitigate this problem in this case.

3) Maybe it's the visualisation? I see that you are using both `ANTIALIAS` and `nearest` in visualing the image. Try removing the `nearest`. Do you still see what you expect?

If you can post some of the images you plot it would help.